# java heap out of memory error while import of 72MB XAR file on tomcat server?

Tags: java, memory-management, memory-leaks, tomcat6

I have 72MB XAR file  provided by opensource project. When i Import it thru UI i get java heap out of memory error. I have mentioned the value of `JAVA_OPTS` 
 as `-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m` as advanced value parameter. My hardware specification is:

1. 32 bit windows operating system and
2. 4 GB RAM
3. And using the webserver as tomcat.

If I increase the value of `JAVA_OPTS` to `-Xms1536m -Xmx1536m`, tomcat does not even start(Probably reason is 32 bit operating system and 4 GB RAM). How should I go about it?

Though same xar file gets imported on 64 bit operating system and 8GB RAM but how should i successfully resolve import of 72MB XAR file on 32 bit OS and 4 GB RAM?

I can not upgrade this client machine due to some restrictions.

Comment: You probably need to use http chunked transfer encoding.

Comment: could you explain little more on that?

Answer (score 4):

I believe when running Java 32 bit the max heap size is 1024m.

I checked several sites and found basically the same response, min and max settngs should not go past 1024m.

-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m

--GP